# Loop through the dataset and display the result in textbox SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a Dataset for suppose consider it as CreditCards

> CreditCards Dataset
>   -------------------------------------------------------|
>
> Id                   Value
>   -------------------------------------------------------|
>
> 1                    Amex
>
> 2                    Discover
>
> 3                    Citi
>
> "             *****   so on****
>   "
>   -------------------------------------------------------|

my report i need to loop through the whole dataset and have to print the like below
                               Amex(1), Discover(2), citi(3)
The dataset will take a **multivalued parameter** consider it as

> id( 1,2,3)

How can i display the values in my report as

> Amex(1), Discover(2), citi(3)

i tried [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a7d59224-0ee5-491e-883b-2e5fcb3edeab/iterate-through-rows-of-dataset-in-reports-custom-code?forum=sqlreportingservices) route, but didnt had any luck.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Amex(1), Discover(2), citi(3)  you need this as result ???

Comment: Yes, thats right @Manoj

Answer (score 0):

Try to write expression for the textbox:

```
=(Field!Value.Value)+" ("+Cstr(Field!ID.Value)+")"
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @PieterGoosen: I agree with you pieter, from that we only get one value.